# Youtube Api v3 restricting result in one language

Tags: utf-8, youtube-api, special-characters

Is there any way to restrict to get result from youtube in one language? My code is almost working nice but it returns some videos that has title or description in other language. For example in Turkish we have word "iş" means work or "aşk" means love. Youtube returns some videos including in its title/description "is","ask". We have speacial charachter in Turkish but youtube makes it resembling to English. How can i avoid from this?
Could it be due to i am encoding my code and database UTF-8?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [region codes](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#regionCode) for the videos, that will help.

E.g. For Turkish videos, you can use regionCode = "TR"

> GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=is&regionCode=TR&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Comment: Yes i know it but it does not work. (Actually, sir, i have sent you a message in fb ) i am using your source code. When i try youtube api explorer by typing region code as TR it does not work as well. Youtube API v2 restricts can language but i cant do it with v3.